# C++ wcstombs_s not working as it should, according to tutorial

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msvcrt

I am going through a tutorial on using Direct3D in C++, and it's been going great and i've been at it for a couple of hours, this is the first bug. I am obviously happy i have had no problems what so ever until now but this wcstombs_s stuff does not seem to work properly at all, i wrote like this:

```
error = wcstombs_s((size_t)&stringLength, (char)m_videoCardDescription, (size_t)128, (const wchar_t)adapterDesc.Description, (size_t)128);
```

According to the tutorial i should not even have to do the (varType) thing, but since it didn't want to work at all, i though it would be necessary to make sure i was following the format instructions Visual Studio gave me, doesn't work still, gives me the message

```
no instance of overloaded function "wcstombs_s" matches the argument list
argument types are: (size_t, char, size_t, wchar_t, size_t)
```

[EDIT]I also tried doing this to make sure i did nothing wrong with the formatting of the variables:

```
size_t st0;
char c0;
size_t st1;
const wchar_t wct0 = 0;
size_t st2;
int test = wcstombs_s(&st0, c0, st1, wct0, st2);
```

Guess what? Did not work either!
This is driving me nuts, please help.

Comment: i also tried removing the const at the adapterDesc.Description, didn't work and it should be a const

Comment: The first parameter of `wcstombs_s` is `size_t*`, not `size_t`. The second is `char*`, not `char`. The fourth is `const wchar_t*`, not `wchar_t`. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but the code as shown makes no sense.

Comment: You should be able to call `wcstombs_s` without any casts, you have 5 of them.